# how to download with splinter knowing direction and name of the file

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, splinter

I am working on python and splinter. I want to download a file from clicking event using splinter. I wrote following code

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser('chrome')
url = "download link"
browser.visit(url)
```

I want to know how to download with splinter knowing URL and name of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splinter is not involved in the download of a file.

Maybe you need to navigate the page to find the exact URL, but then use the regular `requests` library for the download:

```
import requests

url="some.download.link.com"
result = requests.get(url)
with open('file.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result.content)
```

Comment: This answer is unhelpful for my use case, because unless the file being downloaded is publicly available, any authentication or other session-pertinent details are lost when switching HTTP clients.